# Why do i get an Attribute Error when using Neurokit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, attributeerror

Why do i get an attribute error when i run this code in jupyter ? I am trying to figure out how to use Neurokit.

Ive tried to look through the modules one by one, but i seem to find the error.

```
import neurokit as nk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py/master/examples/Bio/bio_100Hz.csv")

# Process the signals
bio = nk.bio_process(ecg=df["ECG"], rsp=df["RSP"], eda=df["EDA"], add=df["Photosensor"], sampling_rate=1000 )
```

Output Message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ad0abf8de45e> in <module>
     11 
     12 # Process the signals
---> 13 bio = nk.bio_process(ecg=df["ECG"], rsp=df["RSP"], eda=df["EDA"], add=df["Photosensor"], sampling_rate=1000 )
     14 # Plot the processed dataframe, normalizing all variables for viewing purpose
     15 nk.z_score(bio["df"]).plot()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neurokit\bio\bio_meta.py in bio_process(ecg, rsp, eda, emg, add, sampling_rate, age, sex, position, ecg_filter_type, ecg_filter_band, ecg_filter_frequency, ecg_segmenter, ecg_quality_model, ecg_hrv_features, eda_alpha, eda_gamma, scr_method, scr_treshold, emg_names, emg_envelope_freqs, emg_envelope_lfreq, emg_activation_treshold, emg_activation_n_above, emg_activation_n_below)
    123     # ECG & RSP
    124     if ecg is not None:
--> 125         ecg = ecg_process(ecg=ecg, rsp=rsp, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, filter_type=ecg_filter_type, filter_band=ecg_filter_band, filter_frequency=ecg_filter_frequency, segmenter=ecg_segmenter, quality_model=ecg_quality_model, hrv_features=ecg_hrv_features, age=age, sex=sex, position=position)
    126         processed_bio["ECG"] = ecg["ECG"]
    127         if rsp is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neurokit\bio\bio_ecg.py in ecg_process(ecg, rsp, sampling_rate, filter_type, filter_band, filter_frequency, segmenter, quality_model, hrv_features, age, sex, position)
    117     # ===============
    118     if quality_model is not None:
--> 119         quality = ecg_signal_quality(cardiac_cycles=processed_ecg["ECG"]["Cardiac_Cycles"], sampling_rate=sampling_rate, rpeaks=processed_ecg["ECG"]["R_Peaks"], quality_model=quality_model)
    120         processed_ecg["ECG"].update(quality)
    121         processed_ecg["df"] = pd.concat([processed_ecg["df"], quality["ECG_Signal_Quality"]], axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\neurokit\bio\bio_ecg.py in ecg_signal_quality(cardiac_cycles, sampling_rate, rpeaks, quality_model)
    355 
    356     if quality_model == "default":
--> 357         model = sklearn.externals.joblib.load(Path.materials() + 'heartbeat_classification.model')
    358     else:
    359         model = sklearn.externals.joblib.load(quality_model)

AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'externals'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could downgrade you scikit-learn version if you don't need the most recent fixes using

```sh
pip install scikit-learn==0.20.1
```

There is an issue to fix this problem in future version:
https://github.com/neuropsychology/NeuroKit.py/issues/101

Comment: Ok Thanks i figured it out !

Answer (score 0):

I'm executing the exact same code as you and run into the same problem.
I followed the link indicated by Louis MAYAUD and there they suggest to just add

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

That solves everything and you don't need to downgrade scikit-learn version

Happy code! :)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately i have changed project and no longer use neurokit.